# Drupal 8 curl 60 error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, drupal

I can't update drupal 8 modules on local because I have the error message

*"Failed to fetch file due to error "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"*

I use Wamp 3 and php 7.0.10. I have tried the solution indicates for this problem :

- Download cacert.pem on curl site and save in "c:\windows"
- Set `curl.cainfo = "c:\Windows\cacert.pem"` and  `openssl.cafile= "c:\Windows\cacert.pem"` on `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.ini` and `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\php.ini` (.simlink)
- Restart all services

The problem is still there.

I have tested many advices on forum :
- Put the cacert.pem in wamp directories and changes paths in 2 php.ini
- Test with other php versions ...

For information Curl is well enabled. I've checked it with phpinfo().

```
   curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.50.1
Age     3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN     Yes
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
NTLMWB  No
SPNEGO  Yes
SSL     Yes
SSPI    Yes
TLS-SRP     No
HTTP2   No
GSSAPI  No
KERBEROS5   Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS    No
PSL     No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    x86_64-pc-win32
SSL Version     OpenSSL/1.0.2h
ZLib Version    1.2.8
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.7.0
```

What is wrong ?

Since many days I test but nothing works.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have private and public key in your pem ?

Comment: Sorry, what is the "pem" ?

Comment: your certification file have extension pem

Comment: I have downloaded the certificat file cacert.pem on curl website

Comment: I don't know if the key is public or private. How can I know it ?

Answer (score 0):

This error message means the distant server did not trust your certificate

see some links about that :

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/resolving-ssl-self-signed-certificate-errors-806029899.html

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-xampp-curl-error-60/

Comment: Why the certificate is considered as self-signed ?

Comment: The problem came from of my firewall. Thank you for your replies.